# Linux Kernel Coding Standards/Style For Nested if-statements

Tags: linux-kernel

I was looking at this link for clarification on the Linux Kernel Coding Style (https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.15/process/coding-style.html#placing-braces-and-spaces)

However I do not see any explanation on how to format nested if-statements. Here is the chunk of code that I am questioning:

```
if (cond1) {
        if (cond2) {
                1 line of code...
        }
 } else {
        1 line of code again...
 }
```

Does the nested if statement need the curly braces, even though it only has 1 line of code? I know that the else statement does need the curly braces, since that is what the docs specify. I am trying to avoid any styling issues that result in my commit getting rejected. Thank you.

Comment: "I do not see any explanation on how to format nested if-statements." - There is **no specific** about nested `if` statements, formatting them follows the same rules as outer `if` statements. "Does the nested if statement need the curly braces, even though it only has 1 line of code?" - Single statement under `if` doesn't require braces. This is explicitly described in the document you show (`if (condition)` + `action();`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Tsyvarev mentioned - there is no specific conventions for nested if-statements.

Regarding single-line if-statements - you don't have to. Keep in mind though that one of the main goals of conventions is to maintain code readability. In the end, your code should be readable. If a curly braces makes your code more readable, even if it is only one line - then use curly braces.